# iOS Rocket socket with ip address not working

Tags: ios, sockets, websocket, ip, socketrocket

I want to make the socket rocket work with ip address instead of host name

I am using Socket Rocket Visit https://github.com/square/SocketRocket#readme   to create real time application on iPhone/ipad ,the library works fine if i use host name , but it doesn't work if i use ip address instead of host name (i get the ip by ping my web server host name)

Tried to resolve ip address to its host name but nothing.

Comment: Can you share the host name and IP you are using?

Comment: i used a generic one exist in this web site http://www.websocket.org/echo.html  , the host name is ws://echo.websocket.org and the ip retrieved by ping the host name

Comment: Host name is the right way to use.. If you have IP then you have to use it as ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and it should work..

Comment: if you check the site websocket.org/echo.html  , and try to replace the host name "ws://echo.websocket.org" with ip "ws://174.129.224.73" it will not work :( , and the same happen in IOS

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution , i used the library "GCDAsyncSocket" it works fine and smooth